# remove the dataframe dynamically

Tags: python

Assume I have created in df1,df2,df3 dataframe created in the current workspace.

If i want to remove the dataframe individually.

```
del df1
del df2
del df3
```

if i want to achieve through loop and get delete dataframe dynamically. I used the below code but its not delete the deleting the dataframe as its just  string where the objects are listed in current sessions.

```
import pandas as pd
sheets=[]    
for var in dir():
    if isinstance(locals()[var], pd.core.frame.DataFrame)  and var[0]!='_':
        sheets.append(var)
        del var  #this is not deleting the dataframe but deleting just a name
```

any thoughts on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about a simple loop?

```
for dataframe in [df1, df2, df3]:
    del dataframe
```

Or if you really want to get the variable name from `locals()` and delete it from there, then:

```
for var in dir():
    if isinstance(locals()[var], pd.core.frame.DataFrame) and var[0]!='_':
        sheets.append(var)
        del locals()[var]
```